# Why wont the randomization in this code work?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, switch-statement

Thank you for answering my original question, and the reason i am simply editing this post for my second question about this code is because the site wont let me make very many questions. my question is why isnt makesjump1 randomly true or false? it always seems to come out true. please help @Yhlas and @codeConcussion

```
var isjumping1 = true;

while(isjumping1) {

var makesjump1 = Math.random()
if(makesjump1 => .51) {
    makesjump1 = true }
else if(makesjump1 <= .50) {
    makesjump1 = false }

var jump1 = prompt("Do you choose to JUMP, or let the fairies help you FLY").toUpperCase()
switch(jump1) {
    case 'JUMP':
        if(makesjump1 = true) {
            console.log("You made the jump on your own, so the fairies reward you with a steel sword(9 DMG)")
            damage = 9;
            weapon = 'steel sword(9 DMG)'; }
        else if(makesjump1 = false) {
            console.log("You attempt the jump but miss it, and are hanging on by a thread")
            console.log("The fairies rescue you, but you got scratched up, doing 3 damge to you.")
            health = health - 3; }
    isjumping1 = false;
    break;
    case 'FLY':
        console.log("The fairies help you over the pit")
        isjumping1 = false;
    break;
    default:
        alert("That was not a choice!")
    break; }
}
```

Comment: When posting real code, you should add a tag for what the language is. It affects syntax coloring and helps others to find the question.

Comment: sorry about that i will add the tag now i forgot

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning it to true with every loop. Use == instead or just...

```
while(isjumping1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(isjumping1==1) - comparison
while(isjumping1=1) - assignment(always returns true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you're assigning the random value to `makesjump1` is incorrect.  It would fail if `Math.random()` returned a value in the range (0.50,0.51).  Instead, try this:

```
var makesjump1 = Math.random()<0.5;
```

Comment: so if i did that it would be if the number is less than 0.5 it would be true, and more than it would be false? thanks for the help i will go replace that part of my code and see the outcome.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the outcome.  It's a quick way of getting a random `true` or `false` value.